# Proving that the quotient manifold is orientable if and only if the group action is orientation-preserving

Tags: differential-geometry, orientation

I'm trying to solve the following exercise in Lee's book.

Suppose M is a connected, oriented smooth manifold and Γ is a discrete group acting freely and properly on M. We say the action is orientation-preserving if for each γ ∈ Γ, the diﬀeomorphism $x\rightarrow γx$ is orientation-preserving. Show that M/Γ is orientable if and only if Γ is orientation-preserving.

Assuming $\Gamma $ to be orientation-preserving, I tried taking a commutative diagram taking an orientation of M to one of M$/\Gamma$ and vice-versa and tried using local diffeomorphism arguments to prove the orientability of M$/\Gamma$. However, I can't make this proof explicit. Nor can I proceed for the other direction.

Can someone please provide a proof for both if and only if parts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this problem, but I'm not sure about what "$\Gamma$ is orientation-preserving" means. Can you define it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the quotient space is orientable. Choose an everywhere non-zero top dimensional differential form (section of the determinant bundle)and pull it back by the covering projection. This gives a global top dimensional form on M. Since the covering map is a local diffeomorphism the pull back is also nowhere zero. So M is orientable.

In this case you do not need to assume that the covering transformations are orientation preserving but once you have the global non-zero n-form on M you can show that they must be.

BTW: You can also show this  by the naturally of the Stiefel-Whitney classes. If the quotient manifold is orientable then the first Stiefel-Whitney class is zero and so pulls back to zero.

Going the other way. If the group of covering transformations is finite then you can average a global non-zero form over the covering maps and this form will descend to the quotient.It will be everywhere non-zero because the covering transformations preserve orientation.

For the general case, I would try choosing compatible local orientations of the fiber spheres in M ( or in the determinant bundle) over coordinate charts that project diffeomorphically onto charts in the base. Then show that compatible local orientations can be chosen over these projections.

Comment: Where is the discreteness used in your argument?

Comment: Good general answer. Maybe worth pointing out that the naturality of Stiefel-Whitney classes applies to $w_1$ of the pull-back bundle, so unless the pull-back of the tangent bundle is isomorphic to the tangent bundle (which it will be for a finite group action), the conclusion is wrong. For example, any manifold maps to $pt$, which has vanishing $w_1$, but not every manifold is orientable.