# Compact & Hausdorff but not Orientable

Tags: general-topology, compactness, quotient-spaces

Imagine $\Bbb{R}^3$ with this equivalence relation $(x,y,z) \sim (x',y',z') \iff  \exists t \in \Bbb{R}^3 - \{0\}:  x'=tx, y'=ty, z'=tz$.

In this case how can I show that $\Bbb{R}^3/\sim$ is **compact** and **hausdorff** but it isn't **orientable**?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your definition of $\sim$ does not make sense ($t \in \mathbb R^3$). Moreover I am sure that you consider $\sim$ on $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This space is the same as $\mathbb R \mathbb P^2 \cup \{ 0 \}$.

But let us try to see it more directly. Let us call your space $X$ (and let us also forget the origin, since it just makes the computations messier). So $X= \mathbb R^3 - \{ 0\} / \sim $.

First, I claim that there is a map $\pi: \mathbb R^3 -\{0\} \to S^2$ and a map $\Pi:S^2 \to X$ such that the following diagram commutes:
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathbb R^3 - \{ 0\} & \xrightarrow{\pi} & S^2 \\
&\searrow & \downarrow \\
&& X
\end{array}
$$

Indeed, $\pi$ is defined by $x \mapsto x/|x|$, and $\Pi$ is defined by sending $x$ to its equivalence class. Note that it is a $2:1$ map.

This proves that $X$ is compact, since it is the image of a compact space. It also proves Hausdorffness, because $\Pi$ is locally a diffeomorphism (explain why and why this is enough).

So $X$ can be identified with $S^2/\mathbb Z_2$, where $\mathbb Z/2$ acts by $x \mapsto -x$.

Here's a sketch of the non-orientability: the group action of $\mathbb Z / 2$ is *not* orientation-preserving on $S^2$, then use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196136/proving-that-the-quotient-manifold-is-orientable-if-and-only-if-the-group-action) old math.stachexchange answer.

Comment: Would you please explain more about $\pi$? I don't know why it is enough to prove $\pi$  is locally a diffeomorphism so that $X$ is hausdorff. Besides I don't know what  a $2:1$ map means. I'll be grateful if you tell me more about it.

Comment: If we do not omit the origin, then $P = \mathbb R^3/\sim$ is not Hausdorff. In fact, the only open neigborhood of $ 0 \in P$ is $P$ itself: If $p : \mathbb R^3 \to P$ denotes the quotient map and $U$ is an open neighborhood of $0 \in P$, then $p^{-1}(0)$ is an open neighborhood of $0 \in \mathbb R^3$ which clearly contains points of all $p^{-1}(x)$ with $x \ne 0$. Thus we must have $p^{-1}(0) = \mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @paul-frost Thank you for your answer. It can’t be compact, am I right?

Comment: @geosd My space $P$ is compact because any open cover of $P$ must contain a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much